# Combine multiple csv files and add/average columns based on matching data

Tags: python

I have a bunch of different csv files in a directory, the first column contains names, the second and third columns contain numbers. I would like to combine all of the rows with same names, and then average the value in the 2nd column and add the value in the 3rd.

```
example csv 1:

John 5 5
Mark 10 5
Peter 20 5

example csv 2:

John 10 5
Mark 20 5
Peter 30 5

Expected combined file:

John 7.5 10
Mark 15 10
Peter 25 10
```

I have this so far, which combines all the files into one:

```
    os.chdir(r'\Pathtofiles')
    extension = 'csv'
    all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
    combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])

I get this result:

John 5 5
Mark 10 5
Peter 20 5
John 10 5
Mark 20 5
Peter 30 5
```

but not sure how to get my expected result

Comment: you can group by names - `df.groupby("name")` and later work with every group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already created `DataFrame` with all data so now you can use [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to group by `name` and next you can use `.agg()` to run different ([aggregation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#aggregation)) functions on different columns in groups.

```
new_df = df.groupby('name').agg({'first':'mean', 'second':'sum'}).reset_index()
```

---

Full working example with data directly in code - so everyone can simply copy and test it.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    ['John', 5, 5],
    ['Mark', 10, 5],
    ['Peter', 20, 5],
    ['John', 10, 5],
    ['Mark', 20, 5],
    ['Peter', 30, 5],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['name', 'first', 'second'])

print(df)

new_df = df.groupby('name').agg({'first':'mean', 'second':'sum'}).reset_index()

print(new_df)
```

Result:

```
    name  first  second
0   John      5       5
1   Mark     10       5
2  Peter     20       5
3   John     10       5
4   Mark     20       5
5  Peter     30       5

    name  first  second
0   John    7.5      10
1   Mark   15.0      10
2  Peter   25.0      10
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the first csv file is named D1 and the second one is D2, and assuming that the column names in the csv files are ['name','num1','num2']:

```
New_Date=D1.merge(D2,left_on=("name"),right_on=("name"),suffixes=("_left","_right"))
New_Date["Average"]=(New_Date["num1_left"]+New_Date["num1_right"])/2
New_Date["Sum"]=New_Date["num2_left"]+New_Date["num2_right"]
New_Date.drop(columns=['num1_left', 'num2_left', 'num2_right', 'num1_right'],inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `csv` module which has `csv.reader` and `csv.writer`. `os.listdir(path)` is used to iterate over files in a particular directory you also need to perform checks weather the file is a directory or not and read permission is granted or not and also ensure that the file is actually a `csv` file.

`person = dict()` is a `dictionary` that holds `name`(str) as **key** a truple of 2 values as **value**. We initialize the person dictionary while reading from `csv` file.

```
import csv
import os

path = "/home/devp/Documents/code/so/python/files"

person = dict()

for file_name in os.listdir(path):
    file_path = os.path.join(path, file_name)
    print(file_path)

    with open(file_path, 'r') as csvfile:
    # creating a csv reader object
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)

        rows = list()
        # extracting each data row one by one

        for row in csvreader:
            if len(row) == 1:
                row = row[0].split(' ')
                if len(row) >2:
                    name = row[0]
                    print(f"{name=}")
                    n1 = float(row[1])
                    n2 = float(row[2])
                    if name in person:
                        person[name] = ((person[name][0]+n1)/2, (person[name][1]+n2)/2)
                    else:
                        person[name] = (n1, n2) 

print(f"{person=}")

with open(os.path.join(path, 'all.csv'), 'w') as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f)
    for name in person:
        csvwriter.writerow([name, person[name][0], person[name][1]])
```

## Output:

```
$ cat files/all.csv 
John,7.5,5.0
Mark,15.0,5.0
Peter,25.0,5.0
```